# New Apex developer - Trigger to stop an insert or update if 2 fields contain the same data

Tags: apex, before-trigger

I have 3 objects.  A Work Ticket with a lookup relationship to Parent Tax Account.
And a Child Tax Account with a Master Detail to the Parent Tax account.

The Rule is if the Work Ticket has a RecordType.name = "Voucher" and a Action = 'DDIV' then the Old Levy and New Levy values on the Parent Tax account can not be the same when the work ticket Voucher Path is changed to 'Valuation.  I added a formula that evaluates to true if the old and new levy values are the same on the Parent Tax Account.  So if any parent tax account has value of true the trigger should return an error message telling the user that the old/new levy values cannot be the same.  If no rows are returned then update the Work Ticket.

My SOQL returns a row with the previous Voucher path value, not the new value it is being inserted/updated to.

```
trigger mcATL_Compare_Levy_Values on mcATL_Work_Ticket__c (before insert, before update) {

    list<mcATL_Work_Ticket__c> compareLevies = trigger.new;
    SYSTEM.debug('ID' + compareLevies);
    mcATL_Work_Ticket__c wt = [SELECT ID,(SELECT id, mcATL_Levy_Comparison__c from Tax_Accounts__r where mcATL_Levy_Comparison__c = 'true')
                             FROM mcATL_Work_Ticket__c WHERE ID =:compareLevies AND RecordType.Name = 'Voucher' AND mcATL_Voucher_Type__c = 'DDIV'];
                            //AND   mcAtl_Voucher_Path__c = 'Valuation' ];
    System.debug('Result' + wt.Id);

    if(wt.size() = 0)  //AND new voucher path = 'Valuation'??? 
    {
        try{
            Update compareLevies;

        } catch(DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e); 
            system.debug(e);   

        }
    }
}
```

This does not work, I get Expression cannot be assigned.

Comment: It helps if you give us the full text of the error message _verbatim_, include the stack trace, and help point out which line the error is pointing to.

Comment: That said, is `wt.size() = 0` a typo, or is that what you have in your code? If it's in your code, then that's your immediate issue. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality check.

Comment: `expression can't be assigned` comes from this line `wt.size() = 0` - you can't assign a scalar to a method invocation. you want `wt.isEmpty()`

Comment: I tried isEmpty(), the variable does not exist.  The SOQL returns the old values if they exist, how do I validate the new values?  ie RecordType = "Voucher', Action = 'DDIV',  levy comparison  has at least 1 row with a value of true and the new value for the voucher path is 'Valuation.  If those values exist in the insert/update do not allow insert/update.

Comment: Also tried if (wt.size()==0)  and receive: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void size() from the type mcATL_Work_Ticket__c